# Python: find sublist with one non important element

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 5], [2, 4, 6], [3, 3, 6]]
```

where each element represents `[x, y, size]` and I'm trying to draw a map of size `8x8`.

```
for x in range(8):
    string = ""
    for y in range(8):
        if [x,y,*] in lst:
           string += *
        else:
           string += "0"
```

Is there a possibility to search for `[x, y, *]` inside a list where `*` can be any number, without iterating over all of its elements?
Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Will the `*` always be in the last position?

Comment: yes * will always be on the last position

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `*` will always be in the last position, you create a `dict` using the `x,y` pair as key.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,5],[2,4,6],[3,3,6]]
>>> m = {(x,y): [x,y,s] for (x,y,s) in lst}
>>> m[2,4]
[2, 4, 6]
```

This will only store one element per `x,y` key, so if there can be multiple with the same `x,y`, wrap the values into lists.

```
>>> m2 = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for x,y,s in lst:
...     m2[x,y].append([x,y,s])
...
>>> m2[2,4]
[[2, 4, 6]]
```